# Reason to take head bath after death rituals

Tags: rituals, death

Why is it recommended that we take head bath on 10th or 11th day after death of family members?

Comment: The reason is to purify the bodies after the period of Asuchi is over..During the Asuchi period there's no point in bathing because it can't make one pure then..

Comment: While coming back from a death ritual, my mother stopped me for entering home, and asked to wash hands and legs she said water will purify the negative energy if any, i said okay.

But on [13th day also there is a pooja is a culture in my region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terahvin),